# Log only shows one of four rows of data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a small Node js application for automatic vehicle location system.
Here is the code for where I am getting trouble.

markerData contains 4 rows but only in the log I can see the last row.

```
for (var i = 0, len = markerData.length; i < len; i++) {
        var thisMarker = markerData[i];

            sql.connect(config, function (err) {
                var request = new sql.Request();                    
                request.input('myval', sql.Int, thisMarker.id);                    
                request.query('SELECT d.id, d.name,  d.lastupdate, p.latitude, p.longitude, p.speed, p.course FROM  dbo.devices AS d INNER JOIN  dbo.positions AS p ON d.positionid = p.id AND d.id = p.deviceid  WHERE        (d.id = @myval)', function (err, recordset2) {



                    if (typeof recordset2 != 'undefined') {                      

                        thisMarker.position.lat = recordset2[0].latitude;
                        thisMarker.position.long = recordset2[0].longitude;

                        console.log(recordset2[0].id);
                    }                                                                       


                });

            });

        }
```

Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `var` is not a block level variable in terms of scope, when `sql' module takes time to connect to the database asynchronously, the synchronous loop may change the value of the variable that's why you have the last row printed since the variable holds the reference to the last object at the time of successful connection.

Instead of `_.each`, I would recommend to use `async` module with `async.each` since you have few asynchronous operation to get rid of a synchronous loop.

You can check for samples here,

http://justinklemm.com/node-js-async-tutorial/

Here is your updated code with `async.each`

-> Install `async` module with `npm install async --save`

-> Then add the below reference in the required place,

```
// Reference
var async = require('async');
```

-> Modified code:

```js
sql.connect(config, function (err) {
   if(err) {
      console.log('Connection error: ');
      console.log(err);
   } else {
     
        async.each(markerData, function(thisMarker, callback) {
             var request = new sql.Request();                    
                    request.input('myval', sql.Int, thisMarker.id);                    
                    request.query('SELECT d.id, d.name,  d.lastupdate, p.latitude, p.longitude, p.speed, p.course FROM  dbo.devices AS d INNER JOIN  dbo.positions AS p ON d.positionid = p.id AND d.id = p.deviceid  WHERE        (d.id = @myval)', function (err, recordset2) {
               if(err) {
                 console.log(err);
                 callback();
              } else {
                        if (typeof recordset2 != 'undefined') {                      
    
                            thisMarker.position.lat = recordset2[0].latitude;
                            thisMarker.position.long = recordset2[0].longitude;
    
                            console.log(recordset2[0].id);
                        } else {
                            console.log('Recordset empty for id: ' + thisMarker.id);
                        }                                                                     
    
                        callback();
                }
            });
          
        }, function(err){
             if(err) {
               console.log(err);
             }
        });
     
   }
  
});
```

Comment: please refresh the question.

Comment: Can you add `console.log(thisMarker.id);` just above `sql.connect(` and check what it prints..

Comment: Okay great, now please move the same line below the `sql.connect` as below and see.. we can do some kind of debugging for this strange issue

Comment: I mean, below the line `sql.connect` and above `var request = new sql.Request(); `

Comment: here only . its prints the last rows id.:(

Comment: below the line sql.connect and above var request = new sql.Request(); shows all 4 rows id.

Comment: but after the sql.connect it only prints the last one

Comment: Do you mean, the last `console.log` in your original code is only printing the last one but the line above `var request = new sql.Request();` is printing 4 times?

Comment: Okay well, now can you move the line `console.log(thisMarker.id);`  just above the line `if (typeof recordset2 != 'undefined') {   `. If it prints 4 times again now then the issue is `recordset2` should be `undefined` for other records and please check them in database whether any record is there for the IDs

Comment: now sometimes it prints all 4 rows id and most of the time 1 rows id. it is not stable. it is actually ajax calls

Comment: yes, it should be better to use with `async.each` to handle the asynchronous properly.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: Please check this link for a sample and search for `async.each` in `http://justinklemm.com/node-js-async-tutorial/` which is the same I have given in the actual answer above.

Comment: actually I am not that much expert in node js. please if possible change my code as per that.

Comment: Sure I will do that for you and will edit the answer and here is the explanation of what might have happened: As `var` is not a block level variable in terms of scope, when `sql' module takes time to connect to the database asynchronously, the synchronous loop may change the value of the variable that's why you have the last row printed since the variable holds the reference to the last object at the time of successful connection.

Comment: I have updated the code above in the answer. Please check and give a try. I have also added few error logging in case of something.

Comment: I have updated a minor change. Please take the latest code above now.

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort and the time . I tried with your modified code but now the some times shows connection closed erro.

Comment: Yes it might be the `sql` module not supporting multiple connections at the same time. Please check its documentation.

Comment: This may be because the `sql` module. Let me change the code a bit differently.

Comment: Okay, I have modified the code a bit by moving a `sql.connect` to top to use a single connection. Just give a try.

Comment: Aruna I have another issue also . I appreciate if you could solve that alsoo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40067130/infowindow-is-not-updating-with-marker-google-maps

Comment: @FirozFasilan sure, I will have a look :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how your library works, but presumably `recordset2` is an array of records. `recordset2[0]` is therefore the first record. If you want the next one you should probably try `recordset2[1]` and so on and so forth.

Arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

You'll probably need to loop through all the elements in the array at some point. use a [`for loop`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) for that:

```
for (var i = 0; i < recordset2.length; i++ {
  console.log(recordset2[i])
}
```

That will print out everything your query returns.

Comment: thanks for the reply but my query actually return one record only .

Comment: each time it should return single result . but my problem is it only loggin the last row of the markerData array

Comment: Can you include your table structure with placeholder content (As similar to real data as possible) in the question then please.